# Canonical XML: whitespace in element-only container?

Tags: xml, xsd, removing-whitespace, xml-signature, canonicalization

I have a simple XML file with an XSD schema, where some elements are allowed to contain only certain elements, e.g.

```xml
<xsd:element name="day" type="xsd:date"/>
<xsd:element name="interval">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="day" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and the XML code:

```xml
<interval>
    <day>2016-08-21</day>
    <day>2016-10-21</day>
</interval>
```

If within the `interval` tags I type anything but whitespace or `day`, it will (correctly) fail to validate. Now, using `lxml` in python, I extracted the canonical version (C14N) of such XML, and I found that the whitespace (those 4 spaces of indentation) were kept (as the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n#Example-WhitespaceInContent) says).

I need then to [digitally sign](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) this document, but I do not understand **why would anyone sign that whitespace**. It seems a weakness to me: **different indentation implies different canonical XML** (and mismatching signatures); but this is an unambiguous case in which that whitespace has *nothing to do* with the represented data (all the more so as the schema would not validate against any meaningful content).

- **Why is that whitespace part of a canonical representation of an XML involved in digital signatures?**
- **Is there any way of enforcing in the XSD the removal of such useless whitespace?**

I was thinking more specifically of the [`whiteSpace` facet](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#d0e1654). By specifying `collapse` the whitespace should be removed on validation; but it seems that `whiteSpace` cannot be applied to a `complexType`, and I could not find a way of combining it with a `sequence`.

- **Can I apply the `whiteSpace` facet to a `complexType` (element only) node?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that whitespace part of a canonical representation of an XML
>   involved in digital signatures?

It's difficult to answer "why" questions, even if you were a member of the working group that published the spec (which I wasn't). I don't know why the spec authors made that decision, but I imagine that a decision either way would inconvenience some users at the expense of others.

> Is there any way of enforcing in the XSD the removal of such useless
>   whitespace?

Whitespace between elements in element-only content models is not considered significant in the PSVI. If you want to physically remove it, a practical way to do this is by copying the validated document with a schema-aware XSLT or XQuery processor, for example

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -s:input.xml -xsd:input.xsd -val:strict -qs:.
```

(The query "." here returns the input document after validation).

> Can I apply the whiteSpace facet to a complexType (element only) node?

No, and you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

The following information was supplied by Pietro Saccardi in an edit to my answer, which I have separated out so that I do not appear to be the author.

In python with lxml there is a remove_blank_text option which would strip it when parsing:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xml = etree.parse('file.xml', parser=parser)
```

MHK observation (from the documentation):

Note that the remove_blank_text option also uses a heuristic if it has no definite knowledge about the document's ignorable whitespace. It will keep blank text nodes that appear after non-blank text nodes at the same level. This is to prevent document-style XML from losing content.

This implies that remove_blank_text is not looking at a schema or DTD to identify element-only content, it is guessing from the instance data. The implication is that it might remove whitespace from an element like

```
<padding>    </padding>
```

that has simple content rather than element-only content.

Comment: Thanks for pulling out and adding these details!